# How can I use foreach instead of Join function?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to convert this `join` operation to `foreach` because this worked only if `Incoming product`'s `materialId` and `depotId` match with `outgoing product`'s `materialId` and `depotId`. But If there is not any outgoing product for same material and depot id with incoming product, I want to display only the amount of incoming product to stock page.
So I should do a foreach that cycles the `incomingProductTotals` and retrieve it's matching outgoing total to do the rest inside the `foreach`. But I could not.

```
var incomingProductTotals = Model.IncomingProduct
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.depotId, x.materialId })
            .Select(g => new
            {
                g.Key.materialId,
                g.Key.depotId,
                total = g.Sum(t => t.amount)
            });

        // retrieve all outgoing product totals (with materialId, depotId and total)
        var outgoingProductTotals = Model.OutgoingProduct
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.depotId, x.materialId })
            .Select(g => new
            {
                g.Key.materialId,
                g.Key.depotId,
                total = g.Sum(t => t.amount)
            });
    var totals = incomingProductTotals
                .Join(
                    outgoingProductTotals,
                    incoming => new { incoming.materialId, incoming.depotId },
                    outgoing => new { outgoing.materialId, outgoing.depotId },
                    (incoming, outgoing) => new
                    {
                        incoming.materialId,
                        incoming.depotId,
                        Total = incoming.total - outgoing.total
                    });

            foreach (var item in totals)
            {
                <tr>
                <td> @item.materialId </td>
                <td> @item.depotId </td>
                <td> @item.Total</td>
                </tr>
            }
```

Comment: You should do the above query related code in controller and pass query result to view so your view will get light weight and render you html efficiently with respect to time and performance. The above view may take time to load and degrade your app performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        var incomingProductTotals = Model.IncomingProduct
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.depotId, x.materialId })
        .Select(g => new
        {
            g.Key.materialId,
            g.Key.depotId,
            total = g.Sum(t => t.amount)
        });

        // retrieve all outgoing product totals (with materialId, depotId and total)
        var outgoingProductTotals = Model.OutgoingProduct
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.depotId, x.materialId })
        .Select(g => new
        {
            g.Key.materialId,
            g.Key.depotId,
            total = g.Sum(t => t.amount)
        });

        foreach(var inProduct in incomingProductTotals)
        {
            var outProduct = outgoingProductTotals.where(p => p.materialId == inProduct.materialId && p.depotId == inProduct.depotId).FirstOrDefault();
            if(outProduct != null)
            {
               <tr>
                   <td> @inProduct.materialId </td>
                   <td> @inProduct.depotId </td>
                   <td> @(inProduct.Total - outProduct.Total)</td>
               </tr>
             }

         }
```